# The buffersize property of LongListSelector is deprecated

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I want to control how many pages are preloaded in a LongListSelector, but I found this property is now deprecated.

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does.

You have data=>load data=>render dataflow. You can optimize both operations, loading data and rendering.

**Loading data:**

1. Handle the ItemRealized event on item X:
2. Check if the item in buffer than load it from buffer (X+N), instead fill the buffer. After loading item you should extend your buffer.

It improves your data loading when data amount is small but items count is big. You load maximum into buffer and have smooth scrolling most of the time, extending buffer on background when user stops scrolling.

**Rendering data:**

There is no direct way to force rendering the data. But here is the hack. LongListSelector determines count of loaded items based on the static item container height. You can set the item container height to fit content (setting Heigth="Auto") and extend it dinamically by placing big image, for example. 
It forces longlistselector render not only items on the screen, but all items which are supposed to be on the screen as they has 0 height property.

BTW data rendering is pretty fast so I think your case is the first one.